# How do I store users on app open without authenticator?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing an app on Android Studio which has virtual currency - 'coins' for example.. and I would like to store user's coins amount on my firebasefirestore database using the cloud firestore.

I do not want them to register using the authenticator to store the coins amount. I just want to store user's phone ID with the coins amount.. how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the user's coin count, you will need some way to identify the user. If you want to identify the user without requiring them to sign in, you can use [Firebase's anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth). Signing users in to Firebase with that, can be as simple as:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
```

After which you can get the UID that uniquely identifies the user with:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

While there are more ways to identify the user, using Firebase Authentication has some advantages for you:

- Since you're storing the data in Cloud Firestore, you can [ensure each user can only access their own data with Firebase's server-side security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication).
- If you change your mind in the future and want to allow users to sign in to your app, you can allow them to [upgrade their anonymous account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) to other providers. In this scenario their UID remains the same, so your data structure won't need to be modified.

Comment: it gives me an error.. I Mean it crahes the app right away after using the getUid() -
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser.getUid()' on a null object reference

Comment: That means you're calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();` before the user is signed in.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use firebase auth.
Simply use firebase Databasereference only. (if any error or misunderstanding, let me know)

For example :

```
Databasereference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("coins");
HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put("uid",something.getText().toString());
hashMap.put("coin",something.getText().toString());
```